# .jar file won't run (InvocationTargetException)

Tags: java

I'm trying to setup FPSMeter app for UI performance test on Android device. [They say](http://fpsmeter.github.io/) I need to install both mobile and desktop parts of the app. There are no issues with the mobile part, but the .jar file of the desktop part doesn't launch.
I've tried launching it via command line, and that's what it returns:

```
java -jar FPSMeterApp.jar
os windows
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Lau
ncherImpl.java:389)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImp
l.java:323)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherIm
pl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(
LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at application.Unpack.extract(Unknown Source)
        at application.Unpack.getFile(Unknown Source)
        at application.Unpack.file(Unknown Source)
        at application.ADB.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at application.Main.start(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162
(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Platfor
mImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.
java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformI
mpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatch
er.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.ja
va:191)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

I have both x86 and x64 latest versions of Java RTE installed, I also tried to install them separately - nothing helps.

I use Windows 7 (x64) under Admin role

Environment variables were set properly.

What should I do to actually launch it?

Comment: What's the Java program?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Like, what is the program you're trying to run?

Comment: executable .jar - FPSMeterApp.jar

Comment: Which java JRE are you running?

Comment: There is console output with this application. Can you give it to us ?  (it should be "os windows" or "unix" then not sure.    Are you in the directory the jar is when you launch it ? `java -jar FPSMeterApp.jar`.  Is the absolute path of the file contains some special char (like space ...)?

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException and how do I fix it?](/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is kind of strange solution (crude hack for sure) but can help you to solve the problem.

First of all, from your stack trace here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at application.Unpack.extract(Unknown Source)
        at application.Unpack.getFile(Unknown Source)
        at application.Unpack.file(Unknown Source)
        at application.ADB.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

... it looks like there is a NPE going on during initialization of some kind of `adb` wrapper (more precisely, during extraction of `adb` bundled within jar file).

This is pretty much all you can deduce from stack trace, so I downloaded jar, tried to run it and got exactly the same error (reproducible on Windows 8.1, jre7(32bit), jre8(32 and 64bit)).

I got curious and decided to poke it around with debugger\decompiler.

Although it is hard to pinpoint exact reason why `application.ADB` misbehaves (due to specifics of how it was compiled) I've got an idea of fast and dirty trick you can use to avoid the problem. Namely, original `application.ADB` can be replaced with dummy stub and you may do `adb` unpacking manually.

Here is how to do it.

1. unzip files `adb.exe`, `AdbWinApi.dll`, `AdbWinUsbApi.dll` located inside `windows` folder inside `FPSMeterApp.jar`
2. put them in the same directory as `FPSMeterApp.jar`
3. compile the following stub class (`javac ADB.java`):

```
package application;

public class ADB
{
  private String ADB_LOCATION = "adb.exe";

  ADB() {
  }

  public String getPath() {
    return this.ADB_LOCATION;
  }
}
```

4. replace `application/ADB.class` inside `FPSMeterApp.jar` with `ADB.class` stub you just compilled
5. you can now run `java -jar FPSMeterApp.jar`

These steps worked for me and I've been able to run jar without exceptions and see connected android devices in the UI.

Comment: I encountered the same problem as the OP, and this didn't work for me. Do you have another solution?